# Deploying SP2010 custom state machine workflows into a production site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a dev environment with VS2010 and SP2010 installed in and a production environment running SP2010.  I have created a state machine workflow in VS2010 and deployed to my dev environment for testing.  Now that I have things working the way I want I need to deploy the workflow into my production environment.

In VS2010 I have selected "Package" and taken the resulting .wsp file and attempted to deploy them on my production site by going to Site Settings -> Solutions and uploading.  I have also activated the solution within the solution gallery and ensured that it is also activated in "Site collection features".  However, the workflow does not show up in Site Settings -> Workflows and I can't seem to out what to do.  I have also tried deploying the .wsp through stsadm addsolution.

What am I missing when deploying a custom built workflow packaged as a wsp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first method of deploying solution by uploading it to Site Settings -> Solutions applies to only sandboxed solutions. Are you sure yours is a sandboxed solution ?

The second method which you tried is a global method of deployment through stsadm.

I would suggest, start from scratch i.e. clean up your local Solutions gallery. and use stsadm operations `addsolution`, `deploysolution` and `activatefeature` to deploy this workfow.

Note that `deploysolution` and `activatefeature` can also be done via UI.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I was missing the activatefeature step, when I was trying this before